# assembly code embedded in c giving a improper operand type error for cmp

Tags: c, assembly, x86, opcode, operand

I have made a program that is supposed to check whether a number is positive, negative, or zero.
When I try to compile the code, it gives a improper operand type error, for line 28, which is the cmp opcode. Am I formatting it wrong, or is there some other problem here?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int input;
int output;


int main (void)
{
       scanf("%d", &input);

__asm
{
    jmp start

negative:   
    mov ebx, -1
    ret
nuetral:
    mov ebx, 0
    ret
positive:
    mov ebx, 1
    ret

start:
    mov eax, input
    mov ebx, other

    cmp 0, eax

    jl negative
    je neutral
    jg positive

    mov output, ebx

}
printf("%d\n", output);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I had fixed that after posting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first operand of the `cmp` instruction must be a register or a memory location, not an immediate value. You need to use `cmp eax, 0` instead. This would also be consistent with your conditional jumps (`jl` would jump if `eax` is negative, etc.).

You may be confusing Intel assembly syntax (which you used) with AT&T syntax, where the order of operands is reversed.

Additionally, your usage of `ret` is incorrect: `ret` is used to return from a function, but there is no function call here. What you need there is a `jmp` to the `mov output, ebx` line.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have an immediate as the first operand to `cmp`.  You need to do `cmp eax, 0` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax of cmp for comparing a register against a constant requires the constant to come second. So `cmp eax, 0` should be fine.

Valid combinations are:

```
cmp reg, reg
cmp reg, mem
cmp mem, reg
cmp reg, const
```